# Using a fetch promise synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need a synchronous function (it can be blocking).

I need to use Fetch, and when the promise is ready, I want to return it on the synchronous function.

Everywhere I look I can't find the answer.

Comment: Seems like an odd request. Why does it have to be synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a synchronous function

Unlikely.

> (it can be blocking).

That is what synchronous means.

Long running blocking functions (including network operations) cause serious usability problems and should be avoided.

> I need to use Fetch, and when the promise is ready, I want to return it on the synchronous function.

That is not possible.

`XMLHttpRequest` has a synchronous mode, although it is deprecated and **should not be used**.

You can activate it by passing `false` as the third parameter to `open`.

```
xhr.open("METHOD as string", "URL as strong", false);
```

`fetch` learned lessons from `XMLHttpRequest` and did not implement anything similar.

---

Learn how to deal with asynchronous code instead. The `async` and `await` keywords will let you write in in a synchronous *style*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't block the main thread like this, the browser won't allow you(or nodejs, since I don't know which). There's no synchronous way to fetch like that. You can instead use `async`/`await` to have your code avoid callbacks. It's probably highly unadvised to do what you want to and there's a better solution, but I can't tell you much more because of lacking context.